# Space issue in table

Tags: tables, multicolumn, cellcolor

I'm making several tables and I'm having troubles with this one (see the pic).
[image]

The code I made to get that output is this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[spanish,es-lcroman]{babel}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=3.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{multicol} 
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2.25cm}|>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}m{6cm}|>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}m{6cm}|}
    \captionsetup{width=0.9\textwidth, font={normalsize,onehalfspacing}, labelfont={bf}}
    \caption[Libro de Edebé - Índice.]{Listado de unidades y contenidos de geometría en el libro de texto de Edebé (Fuente: Elaboración propia)}
    \label{tabla:UnidadesEdebe3} \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\cellcolor{NaranjaPortada}\color{white}\textbf{EDEBÉ}} \\
    \hline
    \endfirsthead  
    
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{ -- \textsc{Continuación de la \cref{tabla:UnidadesEdebe3}} --} \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\cellcolor{NaranjaPortada}\color{white}\textbf{EDEBÉ}} \\
    \hline
    \endhead  
    
    \endlastfoot  
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{ -- \textsc{Continúa en la siguiente página} -- } \\
    \endfoot % Lo que hay antes es el pie de tabla en caso de que salte a otra página.
    
    
    \cellcolor{MoradoJaen} \centering\color{white}\bf \textsc{Unidad 9.} \par Geometría en el plano. &
    \begin{tabular}{lp{5cm}}
        \rowcolor{black!10} 9.1. & Elementos básicos de geom. \\
        \rowcolor{black!5} 9.2. & Rectas. \\
        \rowcolor{black!10} 9.3. & Semirrectas y segmentos. \\
        \rowcolor{black!5} 9.4. & Construcciones con regla y compás. \\
        \rowcolor{black!10} 9.5. & Geometría con recursos digitales. \\
        \rowcolor{black!5} 9.6. & Polígonos. \\
    \end{tabular} &
    \begin{tabular}{lp{4.8cm}}
        \rowcolor{black!10} 9.7. & Polígono regulares. \hfill \\
        \rowcolor{black!5} 9.8. & Tamaño y forma. \\
        \rowcolor{black!10} 9.9. & Traslación y giro. \\
        \rowcolor{black!5} 9.10. & Simetría. \par \ \\
        \rowcolor{black!10} 9.11. & Semejanza. \par \ \\
        \rowcolor{black!5} 9.12. & Mosaicos. \\
    \end{tabular} \\
    \hline
    
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

For some reason, it fits a blank space after the first column and move everything else to the right. Does anyone know why and how to fix it? Seems some kind of displacement due to *tabular* inside cell, but not sure about the reason and I must align text after enumeration somehow... Maybe is some kind of incompatibility?

The table is going to be larger, so I need to be a *longtable* environment. Also, I have to manage it somehow to make first column vertically aligned keeping cell colored.

Thanks.

Comment: How or where are the colors `NaranjaPortada` and `MoradoJaen` defined?

Comment: @Mico As you can suposse, those colors don't matter. They are not the issue nor the reason of the problem. I will check the other answer asap. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? (Observe that I had to, among other adjustments, provide substitutes for the named colors `NaranjaPortada` and `MoradoJaen`.)

[image]

Speaking for myself, I wouldn't say that the alternating shades of light gray do much that could be called useful.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish,es-lcroman]{babel}
\usepackage[vmargin=2.5cm, left=3.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}

\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{width=0.9\textwidth,          
             font={normalsize,onehalfspacing}, 
             labelfont=bf,textfont=it}
\newcommand\mystrut{\vphantom{$X^{\int}$}} % typographic strut

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{
    >{\Centering}m{2.25cm}
    >{\RaggedRight}m{6cm}|
    >{\RaggedRight}m{6cm}|}
    
    %% headers and footers
    \caption[Libro de Edebé - Índice.]{Listado de unidades y contenidos de geometría en el libro de texto de Edebé (Fuente: Elaboración propia)}
    \label{tabla:UnidadesEdebe3} \\
    %\hline
    \rowcolor{orange}
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{\color{white}\textbf{EDEBÉ}\mystrut} \\
    %\hline
    \endfirsthead  
    
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{ -- \textsc{Continuación de la \tablename\ \thetable --}} \\
    %\hline
    \rowcolor{orange}
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{\color{white}\textbf{EDEBÉ}\mystrut} \\
    %\hline
    \endhead  
        
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{ -- \textsc{Continúa en la siguiente página} -- } \\
    \endfoot 

    \hline
    \endlastfoot  

 
    %% body of longtable
    
    \cellcolor{Plum}\color{white}
    \textbf{Unidad~9.} \newline Geometría en el plano. &

    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} l @{\hspace{6pt}} L @{}}
    \rowcolor{black!10} 9.1. & Elementos básicos de geom. \\
    \rowcolor{black!5}  9.2. & Rectas. \\
    \rowcolor{black!10} 9.3. & Semirrectas y segmentos. \\
    \rowcolor{black!5}  9.4. & Construcciones con regla y compás. \\
    \rowcolor{black!10} 9.5. & Geometría con recursos digitales. \\
    \rowcolor{black!5}  9.6. & Polígonos. \\
    \end{tabularx} &

    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} l @{\hspace{6pt}} L @{}}
    \rowcolor{black!10} 9.7. & Polígono regulares. \hfill \\
    \rowcolor{black!5}  9.8. & Tamaño y forma. \\
    \rowcolor{black!10} 9.9. & Traslación y giro. \\
    \rowcolor{black!5}  9.10.& Simetría.  \\
    \rowcolor{black!10} 9.11.& Semejanza.  \\
    \rowcolor{black!5}  9.12.& Mosaicos. \\
    \rowcolor{white}   &  \\ % last two rows are blank
    \rowcolor{white}   & 

    \end{tabularx} \\
    
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So, I guess ```@{length}``` sets space from the start of a column. I've added it and, after a few editions I almost got a precise width. Although I supose there must be a more authomatic setting, it's working.

By the way, do you know why the firts column does not align vertically inside its cell? It has ```m{length}``` in table definition, so it should print that way.

Comment: @Suiron - The argument of `@{\hspace{6pt}}` is not a length *per se* but an instruction (`\hspace`) to insert a certain amount of whitespace (`6pt`, to be precise).

Comment: @Suiron - I'm afraid i dont know either why the contents of the first (i.e., purple) column aren'r centered vertically.